# my pop over making troubles

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, popover

> here is my js fiddle .In this script when I click on the yellow text
>   button a pop over appears but it makes other content goes down.But I
>   need the pop over  appears over the content,not making them
>   down.please can anyone help?

```
<a href="http://jsfiddle.net/chanaka27/uZvAL/embedded/result/">


  [1]: http://jsfiddle.net/chanaka27/uZvAL/embedded/result/</a>
```

Comment: Use absolute positioning.

Comment: Please add the relevant code here, and not just a link to JSFiddle.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your submit-errors's style as below:

```
#submit-errors {
    background-color: #F9EDBE;
    border: 1px solid #F0C36D;
    border-radius: 6px;
    box-shadow: 2px 3px 5px #878585;
    color: #222222;
    display: none;
    font-size: 12px;
    height: 138px;
    margin-left: 200px;
    position: absolute;
    width: 428px;
    z-index: 1;
}
```

I Added following properties

```
z-index: 1;
position: absolute;
```

An absolute position element is positioned relative to the first parent element that has a position other than static. If no such element is found, the containing block is

And z-index to bring it over container

Comment: welcome. Always try to add what you code for solving problem while asking question, and accept answer if answer worked for you. so it will help others.